# Using URL Rewrite 2.0 in IIS7 and cleaning POSTs

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm having some issues with setting up rules in URL Rewrite 2.0 using IIS 7.  I'm working on a website that is a combination of more modern .NET 4.0 stuff all the way back to classic .ASP stuff.  My current task is to try and strip some specific characters out of user input to help prevent against XSS attacks.

I get the basic syntax:

```
<rule name="Rule Name" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="myPage.asp" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="" pattern="" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="" />
</rule>
```

I know I need three steps, 
1)  Ensure that what we're looking at is a post
2)  Identify any of a number of bad characters using regex
3)  Continue the post with those characters stripped out.

The first I believe can be addressed by this:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" />
```

What is frustrating me is the second and third issue.
The second is also an input, but I'm stuck trying to find the best {} variable to put in the input.  Right now I have this:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="[\\\|&lt;>]" />
```

but I know that {REQUEST_URI} is not the right variable to go there.  I've been on the URL rewrite site (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), and I've found the IIS 6.0 list of server variables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx), but I can't seem to find a good list of the variables available to me in 7.0 and above and what they mean.  Is this something anyone has bookmarked somewhere and can pass along?

The third is also giving me issues.  Right now, on some other rules, I have `<action type="AbortRequest" />` set, but for this, I'm not looking to stop the request, I'm looking to just remove the bad characters and continue the POST.  The custom rule setup in IIS looks promising, but it just seems to want to redirect to a URL, not do anything else.  Is this something that's even possible?

I should also note that I'm looking into an IIS Managed Module as an alternative to get what I'm looking for.  Does that sound like a better avenue to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that you can't do it and that I was misinterpreting the scope of the URL rewrite application.  I should be looking at an IIS Managed Module, and will pivot to that in the future.